# Issue in the mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, datetime, biztalk

I am working in creating to get the data from the PostgreSQL and insert in to MS SQL Database. So the field in the PostgreSQL is of datatype `Timestamp without time zone` and this needs to be going in to the field of `DataTime` type in MS SQL DB. I am using the scripting functoid in the map to convert them and insert.Below is the scripting I am using

```
public  string ConvertSampDateRec(string dateReceived)
 {
    DateTime recDate;
    DateTime.TryParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", dateReceived, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out recDate);
    string returnRec = recDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    return returnRec;
 }
```

I am not sure if the format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ` for the TimeStamp without time zone. With this I am getting error like below

`Details:"System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

It is making the  `returnRec` as `0001-01-01T00:00:00` for all the `dateReceived`even if it is not null.I tried even using `DateTimeOffset` but still no help

Comment: Can you give us an idea on what is in the dateReceived string before conversion on null and non-null values?

Comment: @PieterVandenheede dateReceived string holds something like 8/6/2013 1:19:57 PM I changed my format specifier           `if(System.DateTime.TryParseExact(dateReceived, " M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out recDate))` but the  `returnRec` as `0001-01-01T00:00:00`

Comment: Your format starts with a an empty string. This works just fine here if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateReceived,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss 
        tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo
        .InvariantCulture, System.Globalization
        .DateTimeStyles.None, out recDate))
    
    return recDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `0001-01-01T00:00:00` into a SQL database, as the error message shows, the smallest date that can be handled is `1753-01-01T00:00:00`

Also, why aren't you handling the return value from `DateTime.TryParseExact`? You have no way of knowing when it's failing to parse the string, so you are getting the default for a DateTime object (equal to DateTime.MinValue)

Make sure you're handling the return similar to this:

```
private static DateTime _sqlDefaultDateTime = new DateTime(1753, 01, 01);

private void foo()
{
    string parsedDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact())
    {
        parsedDate = _sqlDefaultDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that from the error message,  but when we convert it is automatically making 0001-01-01T00:00:00. Can you tell me if there is something wrong with my code

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Even for non null values it is failing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL databases, but it sounds like you're trying to parse the datetime format incorrectly then

Answer (score 0):

**HOLD ON** everyone.  Sorry, but this keep going around and around, there's two other questions for the exact same thing.

OP needs to use the 'o' format to emit a xs:datetime compatible string so that it can be properly converted to a SQL date time.

This is a BizTalk specific circumstance and this explanation has been offered several times.

There's also some additional handling required which has already been described in another post.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to mark it as a duplicate then please?

Comment: I can't find them anymore it seems. Please disregard my last comment.